# error: no such partition grub rescue>

Tags: grub

I have removed the Ubuntu 10.04 from windows 7 this morning but when restarting the computer  the following error comes: no such partition. grub rescue> 
only responding for commands ls giving

(hd0) (hd0,2) (hd0,1) (hd1)

(hd1) is my flash where i burned the Ubuntu 10.04

and command set gives you

prefix=(hd0,4)/boot/grub
root=hd0,4

How can I make the system usable again?

Answer (score 2):

You have deleted the partition where grub was installed.

1) In case you want to install Ubuntu again you can proceed with a regular installation

2) If you want to keep just windows , you can boot your windows using this [you might need to use hd0,2 depending on where you have installed windows]

```
grub>root (hd0,1)
grub>chainloader +1
grub>boot
```

go into recovery mode  and use "fixmbr" command to rewrite the boot sector